# Can Webapi be used in an application which is not excessed by any external application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, action

I'd read it somewhere that whenever one needs to do data intensive work then Webapi could be used. Ex: autocomplete textbox where we get data from using ajax on key press.

Now someone told me that Webapi shouldn't be used within applications which are not externally accessed. Rather action should be used to the same work as it is capable of returning the data back in a similar fashion to webapi.

I'd like to know your suggestions over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you look at it. If all you need is ajax-ification of your controller actions, then you really don't need Web-API. Your actions can return a JsonResult and it is very easy to consume that from your client side through an AJAX call.

Web-API makes it easy for you to expose you actions to external clients. It supports HTTP protocol and Json and XML payloads automatically, out of the box, without you writing the code for it. Now, there is nothing preventing you from consuming the same Web-API actions from your own internal clients in an AJAX manner.

So the answer to your question depends on your design. If you don't have external clients, then there is no string need for you to have Web-API. Your standard controller actions can do the job.

Comment: So is there any difference in terms of Webapi and Actions processing of data. What I'd observed is that we need to convert our model items to json while that's inherent in Webapi. Is there anything more that I can help me to support usage of Webapi for closed ended applications.

Comment: Your observation is correct. Take at a look at this page (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results) for more details on the Web-API return types. That gives you an idea about the extra control you get in directly controlling HttpResponseMessage.